# How to get row count after JOIN in Hibernate Criteria?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, criteria

I try to create request:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteia(User.class);
criteria.setFetchMode(field, FetchMode.JOIN);
int count1 = criteria.list().size(); //340
Number count2 = (Number) criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult(); //279
```

How to return `340` without calling `criteria.list().size()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think while using `Projections.rowCount()` hibernate ignores

`criteria.setFetchMode(field, FetchMode.JOIN);`

You can use `createAlias`

`criteria.createAlias("field","field", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);`

Check query generated by hibernate in both the cases by using `hibernate.show_sql` in Hibernate configuration file

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional